# trapped inside a Graph : Find paths along edges that do not cross any edges

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, geometry, graph

This is a graph based platformer level and the round shapes are creatures.
[image: level sample]

I am looking for a path traveling along edges that does not cross other edges(To simulate the creature crawling on the floors and walls).

Here is what the correct path would look like:[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When traversing the graph, [always turn the same direction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm#Wall_follower). You can use cross product to check what is the left or rightmost direction in a junction.